# Nginx try_files loads blank page when passed with variable path

Tags: nginx, single-page-application, nginx-location

I am setting up nginx to work with a React SPA. The page loads fine when I do not include a variable path (/rsvp/). But when I try (/rsvp/S0mEtH1NG), it will download the index, manifest, css files... but it doesn't actually apply those things to the index.html. I pretty much just see my index.html with nothing actually loaded.

My config looks something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name something.com;

    location / {
        root /srv/something.com/webroot;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /rsvp {
        alias /srv/rsvp/build;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /rsvp/index.html;
    }
}
```

If I have `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html`, it will load the index.html of the root (/) but with a similar issue in that it doesn't use any of the css.

Thanks for help, its much appreciated!

Comment: You have a missing `;`.

Comment: Thanks! (fixed but was just from manually typing out the config)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [long standing issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) with `alias` and `try_files`. I would avoid using those directives within the same block. Try:

```
location /rsvp {
    alias /srv/rsvp/build;
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /rsvp/index.html? last; }
}
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Hmm... still no luck. My index.html gets loaded in both cases and the other files appear to download fine when looking at the network tab. It just doesn't apply the javascript or css.
Do you think this may not be a nginx error? Everything works fine though when I navigate to /rsvp/ just not /rsvp/*.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it was an issue with the react router. Went ahead and marked answer correct though for alias/try_files knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: the `alias` directive cannot be used inside the named location block

Comment: This is a limitation of `alias` directive, so that was my case, not that something wrong with the answer. However, I did a positive vote on your answer.

Comment: Use `root` rather than `alias` in a named `location`. Otherwise, post the details of the problem and your configuration as a new question. Thanks @AamirR

Comment: I have a `root` clause directly in `server` block, and I need to override that `root` in named `location` block, using `root` did not work either.